# how to count xml specific element numbers using python?

Tags: python, xml

Hi I'm trying to know how to count specific element numbers in XML using python.
please see example as following

If i wanted to count number of BBB under the first AAA what would i do ?
There are 3 BBB under the first AAA as you can see.

```
<data>
    <AAA>  -> The first AAA
        <CCC>
            <BBB>This</BBB>
        </CCC>
        <CCC>  
            <BBB>is</BBB>
        </CCC>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>test1</BBB>
        </CCC>
    </AAA>

    <AAA>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>This is test</BBB>
        </CCC>
    </AAA>

    <AAA>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>222222</BBB>
        </CCC>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>333333</BBB>
        </CCC>      
    </AAA>
```

and this is my code to count those.

```
a=0

for AAA in root.findall('AAA')[a]:
    for CCC in AAA.findall('CCC'):
        for BBB in CCC.findall('BBB'):
            count = BBB.count()
            print(count)
```

but it doesn't count even though no error.
What's wrong? i need some advice please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ElementTree

**Demo:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = ET.fromstring(data)

for AAA in doc.findall('AAA'):
    print len(AAA.findall('CCC'))
```

**Output:**

```
3
1
2
```

Comment: Thank you Rakesh. it works very well when using .parse method also

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

xml_text = ElementTree.parse('your_file.xml')
dom = xml_text.getroot()
results = sum([1 for entry in dom.getiterator('BBB')])
print(results)
```